# How to test race condition with async unit tests using NUnit?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

This is the code I'm trying to test for a racing condition,
I have a legacy code which I can change to a certain extent.
Inside my main function, I have a function which returns a Task that we await and another function for UI that must not be blocked because it runs on a different thread.

In the original code we do not care about the result we are just initializing some classes, and I test that the ViewModel is not null.

In the example code I gave here, I changed the code to exemplify the problem of the race condition. 
Currently, my test will fail. **How do I properly test my racing condition**?

```
 [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Myclass tempClass = new Myclass();
            tempClass.CreateImage();
            Assert.AreEqual(3, tempClass.Sum);
        }
    }

    public class Myclass
    {
        public int Sum;

        public Myclass()
        {
            Sum = 0;
        }
        public async Task CreateImage()
        {
            await InternalFunction();
            await Task.Run(() => Physics());
        }

        public async Task InternalFunction()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Math();
            });
        }

        public void Math()
        {
            Sum += 1;
        }

        public void Physics()
        {
            Sum += 2;
        }
    }
```

If I run the test, the sum property will be 1, and not 3 as expected. How do I change the code to be able to perform all of the flow of `CreateImage()` function and only once all of the threads are done, I want to assert the result/content of TempClass.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Why don't you just `await` the `CreateImage()` call in your unit test? That way, you won't execute the assert until all the operations have completed. What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? What have you _tried_? Why didn't that work?

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the feedback I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to await the code in the test itself as well, otherwise the Aseert will take place before the code has completed:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            Myclass tempClass = new Myclass();
            await tempClass.CreateImage();
            Assert.AreEqual(3, tempClass.Sum);
        }
```

But to me this code has some pifalls. There is a lot of wrapping synchronous code in `Task.Run` which won't give any benefits as it is right now. Also `Sum` is not threadsafe so if at any point in time it will be accessed by threads concurrent bad things can happen.

Answer (score 2):

The `CreateImage` method is async, however your unit test method isn't, so your test may complete before CreateImage is finished.

You didn't specify which version of NUnit you're using, but the following works in the latest version of NUnit 3

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        Myclass tempClass = new Myclass();
        await tempClass.CreateImage();
        Assert.AreEqual(3, tempClass.Sum);
    }
}
```

---

Of course, This assumes that `MyClass` is thread-safe - If your real code uses multiple threads concurrently modifying the state of a `MyClass` instance, then you may also need to consider using a synchronisation mechanism such as one of those built into the BCL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/synchronizing-data-for-multithreading

Also, you might consider using some of the async-friendly helpers developed by Stephen Cleary - https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx